# String ordering with arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a string list with 20 strings each line. The fisrt line means "tasks", the second "dependences between tasks" e the third "number of hours to each task". I would like to order it according to 3 criteria. I also would like to allocate this tasks to 2 developers ( I callled them Cp1 and Cp2).

My criteria:

- if string X is equal to 0 add it to the developer with less hours.
- if task dependence were already performed (completed), add it to the developer with less hours.
- if task despendence block the next task and there is no more tasks without depencence, calc the number of inactive hours add it to the developer with less hours.

my input has 3 lines:

> t14 t18 t7 t12 t15 t5 t16 t10 t4 t19 t20 t6 t1 t13 t9 t8 t11 t17 t2 t3
>
> t17 t2 t4 t16 t18 t4 t19 t4 0 t5 t1 t4 0 0 t2 t5 t14 t19 0 0
>
> 4 8 2 4 8 40 2 2 4 2 24 2 6 8 2 2 5 10 16 16

my result should be:

> Cp1: t4 t7 t10 t20 t6 t13 t2 t14 t18 t15 - 78 hours
>
> Cp2: t1 t5 t19 t16 t12 t8 t17 t9 t11 t3 - 89

My code is giving this WRONG output:

> Cp1: [t4, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2]  Hours: 552
>
> Cp2: [t1, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20]  Hours: 550

**Why my code is giving more than 20 strings? It should give me 20 strings distributed between the two CPs.**

**Why my code is no giving the correct ordering?**

My code:

```
public int calcFitness(int indv) {

    String linha1 = individualID.get(indv);     
        idQe = linha1.split(" ");
    String linha2 = individualDep.get(indv);    
        depQe= linha2.split(" ");   
    String linha3 = individualHour.get(indv);
        hourQe = linha3.split(" ");
    String linha4 = individualEmpl.get(indv);
        emplQe = linha4.split(" "); 


        int count1 =0;
        int count2 =0;
        int idle =0;

        for (int x=0; x<idQe.length;x++){   
    //      int y = x + 1;
            for(int j=0;j<depQe.length;j++){    
                if(depQe[j].equals("0")){
                            if (count1<=count2){    
                                        Cp1.add(idQe[j]);
                                        Cp1Hour.add(hourQe[j]);
                                        Cp1Dep.add(depQe[j]);
                                        count1 += Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]);
                                        }
                            else if(count2<count1){
                                Cp2.add(idQe[j]);
                                Cp2Hour.add(hourQe[j]);
                                Cp2Dep.add(depQe[j]);
                                count2 += Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]);  
                                        }
                            }
                else if ((Cp1.contains(depQe[j])||(Cp2.contains(depQe[j])))){
                        if (count1<=count2){
                            if (!Cp1.contains(depQe[j])){
                                idle = Math.abs(count2-count1);
                                count1 += idle;
                                Cp1.add(idQe[j]);
                                Cp1Hour.add(hourQe[j]);
                                Cp1Dep.add(depQe[j]);
                                count1 += Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]);
                                        }
                                            else {                                  
                                                    Cp1.add(idQe[j]);
                                                    Cp1Hour.add(hourQe[j]);
                                                    Cp1Dep.add(depQe[j]);
                                                    count1 += Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]);
                                                    }
                                        }
                        else if(count2<count1){
                            if (!Cp2.contains(depQe[j])){
                                idle = Math.abs(count1-count2);
                                count2 += idle;
                                Cp2.add(idQe[j]);
                                Cp2Hour.add(hourQe[j]);
                                Cp2Dep.add(depQe[j]);
                                count2 += Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]);  
                                    }
                                                else{
                                                    Cp2.add(idQe[j]);
                                                    Cp2Hour.add(hourQe[j]);
                                                    Cp2Dep.add(depQe[j]);
                                                    count2 += Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]);
                                                        }
                                }               
                            }
                    j++;
                        }


                    }
```

I made some changes in the code. My problem now is how to start reading the first string after add a new string?

I would like to start reading the list at the begining after add a new string. However, if such string is already added, I would like to jump and get the next. How I could do that? At the end, I whould like to have 20 strings distributed in 2 developers or lists.

My code:

```
    for (int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < taskQe.length; taskIndex++) {
        String currentTask = taskQe[taskIndex];
        String currentDep = depQe[taskIndex];
        String currentHour = hourQe[taskIndex];
        System.out.println("task: [" + currentTask + "], dep: [" + currentDep + "], hours: [" + currentHour + "]");

        int hour = Integer.parseInt(currentHour);

        if (currentDep.equals("0")) {
        //  System.out.println ("axhou 0");
            if (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours) {
                Cp1.add(currentTask);
                Cp1Hour.add(hour);
                Cp1Dep.add(currentDep);
                Cp1TotalHours += hour;   
            } else {
                Cp2.add(currentTask);
                Cp2Hour.add(hour);
                Cp2Dep.add(currentDep);
                Cp2TotalHours += hour;
            }

        } else if (Cp1.contains(currentDep) || Cp2.contains(currentDep)) {
            //System.out.println ("achou dep" + currentDep );
            for (int i=0; i<=taskIndex; i++) {
            if (depQe[i].equals(currentDep)){
                System.out.println ("achou dep i and curr" + (taskQe[i]) + currentDep );
                if ((Cp1.contains(currentDep)&& (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours))){
                    Cp1.add(taskQe[i]);
                    Cp1Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                    Cp1Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                    Cp1TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                }
                else if ((Cp2.contains(currentDep)&& (Cp2TotalHours < Cp1TotalHours))){
                    Cp2.add(taskQe[i]);
                    Cp2Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                    Cp2Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                    Cp2TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                }
                else if ((!Cp1.contains(currentDep)&& (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours))){
                       Cp1.add(taskQe[i]);
                       Cp1Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                       Cp1Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                       Cp1TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));  
                /*  for (int j=0; j<taskQe.length; j++) {   
                       if(depQe[i].equals(taskQe[j]))
                           idle = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]) - (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i])));
                           Cp1TotalHours=+idle;
                    }*/
                }
                else if ((!Cp2.contains(currentDep)&& (Cp2TotalHours < Cp1TotalHours))){
                    Cp2.add(taskQe[i]);
                    Cp2Hour.add(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i]));
                    Cp2Dep.add(depQe[i]);
                    Cp2TotalHours += (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i])); 
                /*   for (int j=0; j<taskQe.length; j++) {  
                    if(depQe[i].equals(taskQe[j]))
                            idle = Math.abs(Integer.parseInt(hourQe[j]) - (Integer.parseInt(hourQe[i])));
                            Cp2TotalHours=+idle;
                        }*/
                   }
                }
         }

        }
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: My code is not working. At the end my outp is: >Cp1: [t4, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2, t4, t1, t9, t2]  Hours: 552
>Cp2: [t1, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20, t7, t20]  Hours: 550

Comment: Use objects! This will make your life much simpler. Have a `Task` and a `Developer` and read your data accordingly. Java is OO, use its power.

Comment: Also, in Java variables are in `camelCase`.

Comment: #Boris the Spider I am a beginner in Java. I am looking for something simple. I am spent the last two weeks doing that. I want to fix this code.

Comment: Using objects as @Boris said _will_ make things simpler.

Comment: At the moment I prefer to fix my current code. I am not confident enough to use objects. First, I have to learn how to use them.

Comment: Could you explain what this mean? "if task despendence block the next task and there is no more tasks without depencence, calc the number of inactive hours add it to the developer with less hours."

Comment: @igreen I am coding a simulator. I have a list of tasks (line 1) and its attributes (line 2 & 3). I am trying to simulate the task allocation for 2 devs. However, some dependence my lock other tasks.

Comment: "add it to the developer with less hours" which: the task or the dep?

Answer (score 0):

You can continue with code. you first problem is the inner loop. you should use one index. (this code still does not provide the result you wrote.) but this is closer:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.*;
public class Test1 {
   List<String> Cp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   List<String> Cp1Dep = new ArrayList<String>();
   List<Integer> Cp1Hour = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   List<String> Cp2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   List<String> Cp2Dep = new ArrayList<String>();
   List<Integer> Cp2Hour = new ArrayList<Integer>();

   int Cp1TotalHours = 0;
   int Cp2TotalHours = 0;
   int idle = 0;

   public void calcFitness() {
     String linha1 = "t14 t18 t7 t12 t15 t5 t16 t10 t4 t19 t20 t6 t1 t13 t9 t8 t11 t17 t2 t3";
     String[] taskQe = linha1.split(" ");
     String linha2 = "t17 t2 t4 t16 t18 t4 t19 t4 0 t5 t1 t4 0 0 t2 t5 t14 t19 0 0";
     String[] depQe = linha2.split(" ");
     String linha3 = "4 8 2 4 8 40 2 2 4 2 24 2 6 8 2 2 5 10 16 16";
     String[] hourQe = linha3.split(" ");

     for (int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < taskQe.length; taskIndex++) {
        String currentTask = taskQe[taskIndex];
        String currentDep = depQe[taskIndex];
        String currentHour = hourQe[taskIndex];
        System.out.println("task: [" + currentTask + "], dep: [" + currentDep + "], hours: [" + currentHour + "]");

        int hour = Integer.parseInt(currentHour);

        if (currentDep.equals("0")) {
            if (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours) {
                Cp1.add(currentTask);
                Cp1Hour.add(hour);
                Cp1Dep.add(currentDep);
                Cp1TotalHours += hour;
            } else {
                Cp2.add(currentTask);
                Cp2Hour.add(hour);
                Cp2Dep.add(currentDep);
                Cp2TotalHours += hour;
            }
        } else if (Cp1.contains(currentDep) || Cp2.contains(currentDep)) {
            if (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours) {
                if (!Cp1.contains(currentDep)) {
                    idle = Math.abs(Cp2TotalHours - Cp1TotalHours);
                    Cp1.add(currentTask);
                    Cp1Hour.add(hour);
                    Cp1Dep.add(currentDep);
                    Cp1TotalHours += hour;
                } else {
                    Cp1.add(currentTask);
                    Cp1Hour.add(hour);
                    Cp1Dep.add(currentDep);
                    Cp1TotalHours += hour;
                }
            } else {
                if (!Cp2.contains(currentDep)) {
                    idle = Math.abs(Cp1TotalHours - Cp2TotalHours);
                    Cp2.add(currentTask);
                    Cp2Hour.add(hour);
                    Cp2Dep.add(currentDep);
                    Cp2TotalHours += hour;
                } else {
                    Cp2.add(currentTask);
                    Cp2Hour.add(hour);
                    Cp2Dep.add(currentDep);
                    Cp2TotalHours += hour;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours) {
                Cp1.add(currentTask);
                Cp1Hour.add(hour);
                Cp1Dep.add(currentDep);
                Cp1TotalHours += hour;
            } else {
                Cp2.add(currentTask);
                Cp2Hour.add(hour);
                Cp2Dep.add(currentDep);
                Cp2TotalHours += hour;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Cp1 tasks: " + this.Cp1 + ", hours: [" + this.Cp1TotalHours + "]");
        System.out.println("Cp2 tasks: " + this.Cp2 + ", hours: [" + this.Cp2TotalHours + "]");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test1 test1 = new Test1();

    test1.calcFitness();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Cp1: " + test1.Cp1 + " hours: " + test1.Cp1TotalHours);
    System.out.println("Cp2: " + test1.Cp2 + " hours: " + test1.Cp2TotalHours);
    //Cp1: t4 t7 t10 t20 t6 t13 t2 t14 t18 t15 - 78 hours

    //Cp2: t1 t5 t19 t16 t12 t8 t17 t9 t11 t3 - 89

}
```

}

Comment: I am running the code but it not giving the correct output. Your code is giving this output:  Cp1 tasks: [t14, t7, t12, t5, t6, t13, t11, t2], hours: [81]
---Cp2 tasks: [t18, t15, t16, t10, t4, t19, t20, t1, t9, t8, t17, t3], hours: [86] ----The fisrt task to CP1 should be t4 because its dependence is 0.

Comment: After add a task to one developer, I start again at the begining of the string list.

Comment: I found the bug in the code. How I do to set currentTask and currentDep start at position 0 after add an task to one CP? In other words, I would like to start again from first after find and add one task.

Comment: So after you found it `taskIndex = 0`

Comment: I tried to use 'taskIndex = 0' but does not work. I am not sure if I put in the right place in the code.

Comment: Could you clarify the 3 roles you write I don't understand them. Where you put `taskIndex = 0;`

Comment: the 3 roles are working. The problem is that I want to add all 20 strings. When the code find a dependence or 0, it add the string and get the next position. I would like to get the fisrt position besides get the next position. Thus, I can make sure that all strings were added.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would follow advices from comments, because if you finish it, it will be code terrible to read and maintain, and far away from good practices. However if you don't want to, I will try to help a little bit. It is not a direct solution, but maybe it will help if I share my reflections.
In my opinion, essential misunderstanding in yours(both of you) code is a equal level of both main loops. I mean, the loop looking for 0, and looking for dependence of tasks, works at same moment.

- in Joshi 83 code, because of that, it could find a most of 0, but it disturbed desired input, and quick blocks dependencies,
- in igreen code, he add a option to add task if non of above criteria is met, so it add it with first loop;

But if I understand Joshi83 expectations, he want something else. It is not linear adding tasks, its more: if you find 0, track a dependant tasks, if there is no more, look for another 0, but meanwhile if other conditions are true, divide rest of task. Just try to draw a sketch of Jhoshi83 expected output order, it look quite complicated.
[image]

Number in brackets is a criteria to enter a ArrayList. This image is pathetic, but it shows how complicated it is anyway :P
I think you should us at least two level main loops:

- first loop find beginning of dependency chain,
- second main loop start tracking dependencies, and if you find 0, then start another chains

In a process you can divide task between them like you wanted. Also I think it would be good idea to change String[] for ArrayList, then you can remove assigned tasks, and adding loops will not cause doubling of tasks. You can do this like that:

```
ArrayList<String> idQe = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(linha1.split(" ")));
```

and then use idQe.get(j), not idQe[j].

*** EDIT ***

Ok, I tried but I have no idea, how implement all criteria. But maybe you will find something useful in this code. This is changed version of yours updated code. I just want to underline, it is not how I think it should be done! This is what I was able to do with your code. My solution is not too elegant, but still check this out:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class Test {
    List<String> Cp1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> Cp1Dep = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> Cp1Hour = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> Cp2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> Cp2Dep = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> Cp2Hour = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean order = false;
    int Cp1TotalHours;
    int Cp2TotalHours;

    int idle = 0;

    public void calcFitness() {
        // everything in ArrayLists
        String linha1 = "t14 t18 t7 t12 t15 t5 t16 t10 t4 t19 t20 t6 t1 t13 t9 t8 t11 t17 t2 t3";
        ArrayList<String> taskQe = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(linha1.split(" ")));
        System.out.println(taskQe.toString());
        String linha2 = "t17 t2 t4 t16 t18 t4 t19 t4 0 t5 t1 t4 0 0 t2 t5 t14 t19 0 0";
        ArrayList<String> depQe = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(linha2.split(" ")));
        System.out.println(depQe.toString());
        String linha3 = "4 8 2 4 8 40 2 2 4 2 24 2 6 8 2 2 5 10 16 16";
        ArrayList<String> hourQe = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(linha3.split(" ")));

        //Loop for finding first task
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            if (depQe.get(i).equals("0")) {
                if (Cp1Hour.size()<=Cp2Hour.size() ) {
                    Cp1.add(taskQe.get(i));
                    Cp1Hour.add(hourQe.get(i));
                    Cp1Dep.add(depQe.get(i));
                    System.out.println("CP1"+depQe.get(i));
                }else{
                    Cp2.add(taskQe.get(i));
                    Cp2Hour.add(hourQe.get(i));
                    Cp2Dep.add(depQe.get(i));
                    System.out.println("CP2"+depQe.get(i));
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println(depQe.get(i));
            }
        }

        //removing first tasks
        int num1 = taskQe.indexOf(Cp1.get(0));
        taskQe.remove(num1);
        depQe.remove(num1);
        hourQe.remove(num1);
        int num2 = taskQe.indexOf(Cp2.get(0));
        taskQe.remove(num2);
        depQe.remove(num2);
        hourQe.remove(num2);
        System.out.println(taskQe.toString());


        while(!taskQe.isEmpty()){
        for (int taskIndex = 0; taskIndex < taskQe.size(); taskIndex++) {
            String currentTask = taskQe.get(taskIndex);
            String currentDep = depQe.get(taskIndex);
            String currentHour = hourQe.get(taskIndex);
            System.out.println("task: [" + currentTask + "], dep: [" + currentDep + "], hours: [" + currentHour + "]");

            int hour = Integer.parseInt(currentHour);

            if (currentDep.equals("0")) {
                //if (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours) {       //   you can try
                if (Cp1Hour.size() <= Cp2Hour.size()){         //   both options
                    Cp1.add(currentTask);
                    Cp1Hour.add(currentHour);
                    Cp1Dep.add(currentDep);
                    Cp1TotalHours += hour;
                } else {
                    Cp2.add(currentTask);
                    Cp2Hour.add(currentHour);
                    Cp2Dep.add(currentDep);
                    Cp2TotalHours += hour;
                }
                //remove
                taskQe.remove(taskIndex);
                depQe.remove(taskIndex);
                hourQe.remove(taskIndex);
                taskIndex = 0;                           // try with and without
            } else if (Cp1.contains(currentDep) || Cp2.contains(currentDep)) {
                //if (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours) {       //   you can try
                if (Cp1Hour.size() <= Cp2Hour.size()){         //   both options
                    if (!Cp1.contains(currentDep)) {
                        //idle = Math.abs(Cp2TotalHours - Cp1TotalHours);
                        Cp1.add(currentTask);
                        Cp1Hour.add(currentHour);
                        Cp1Dep.add(currentDep);
                        Cp1TotalHours += idle + hour;
                    } else {
                        Cp1.add(currentTask);
                        Cp1Hour.add(currentHour);
                        Cp1Dep.add(currentDep);
                        Cp1TotalHours += hour;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!Cp2.contains(currentDep)) {
                        //idle = Math.abs(Cp1TotalHours - Cp2TotalHours);
                        Cp2.add(currentTask);
                        Cp2Hour.add(currentHour);
                        Cp2Dep.add(currentDep);
                        Cp2TotalHours += idle + hour;
                    } else {
                        Cp2.add(currentTask);
                        Cp2Hour.add(currentHour);
                        Cp2Dep.add(currentDep);
                        Cp2TotalHours += hour;
                    }
                }
                //remove
                taskQe.remove(taskIndex);
                depQe.remove(taskIndex);
                hourQe.remove(taskIndex);

                //taskIndex = 0;
            }

        }

        }
        System.out.println(Cp1 +" - "+ Cp1TotalHours +"hours");
        System.out.println(Cp2 +" - "+ Cp2TotalHours +"hours");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test test1 = new Test();

        test1.calcFitness();

        //Cp1: t4 t7 t10 t20 t6 t13 t2 t14 t18 t15 - 78 hours

        //Cp2: t1 t5 t19 t16 t12 t8 t17 t9 t11 t3 - 89

    }
}
```

I need to admit, that I was wrong, the nested loops structur is not so important. There are couple lines which you can try for different outputs, like these:

- f (Cp1Hour.size() <= Cp2Hour.size()){ 2x taskIndex = 0; no idle:
         Cp1:[t4, t7, t10, t16, t20, t13, t17, t18, t9, t14] - 62hours Cp2:[t1, t5,    t19, t12, t6, t8, t2, t15, t3, t11] - 95hours
- with idle:

  Cp1:[t4, t7, t10, t16, t20, t13, t17, t18, t9, t14] - 120hours Cp2[t1, t5,
  t19, t12, t6, t8, t2, t15, t3, t11] - 145hours.
- if (Cp1TotalHours <= Cp2TotalHours) { 2x taskIndex = 0; no idle:
  Cp1:[t4, t7, t10, t19, t16, t12, t20, t6, t13, t2, t9, t3] - 80hours
  Cp2:[t1, t5, t8, t17, t18, t15, t14, t11] - 77hours
- with idle: Cp1:[t4, t7, t10, t19, t12, t6, t13, t8, t2, t15, t3] -
  120hours Cp2:[t1, t5, t16, t20, t17, t18, t9, t14, t11] - 115hours
- (Cp1Hour.size() <= Cp2Hour.size()){ no taskIndex = 0 in (if 0) loop;
  no idle:
  Cp1:[t4, t7, t10, t13, t8, t3, t2, t15, t14, t12] - 62hours
  Cp2:[t1, t5, t20, t19, t17, t16, t18, t9, t6, t11] - 95hours

In many cases, its divide input to 2 arrays for 10 string. The beginning is as you wanted, but rest is more or less different. Still I think it is step forward. But once again, it is badly written, sorry for that.

Comment: Your comment does not help me at all.:(

Comment: @Jsi83 Sorry. Maybe you should rethink your goals, simplify conditions a little bit, then when you succeed you can try to implement other.

Comment: My code is almost working. My problem is logic. Could you hep me in that?

Comment: @Jsi83 What you mean by almost working? What you done aleady? Whats is working?

Comment: My code finds 0 and dependences. My code add to two different Cps. But my code does NOT start the begining after add a new string to a Cp. Thus, not all 20 string was added. I have try to set up `taskIndex=0`, but it does not work.

Comment: Now the code is gives 20 string. It is working now, but the sequence still not working.

Comment: Thank you @m.cekiera. Now my code is adding 20 string. How could I code this role: "If there is no more available tasks, add idle hours". It means if there is no more tasks availabe( prevoius dependence has been completed or it is 0),  the developer X should wait  until developer y complete such task.

Comment: @Jsi83 i don't fully understand how these idle hours works, it is hard to read this from your desired output ;/